# Only left hand column items in a 2 by 2 grid are transitioning margin on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I can't work out why my left hand column's margin transitions on hover, but not the right side?

At first I thought it was my `a` tags, making them `display:block` has not enabled the right hand column to transition.

I am using a selector `[class^="col-"]` as a column's width may change. Will this have something to do with its failure?

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-left:3vw;
  padding-right:3vw;
}

main {
  padding-top:200px;
  padding-bottom:200px;
}

h2 {
  line-height: 1.3;
  letter-spacing: .046rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem
}

.col-5-5 {
  width:45%
}

a,a:hover,a:visited,a:focus,a:active {
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.pic {
  padding-bottom:65%;
}

.column {
  float:left;
  display:block;
}

.column.right {
  float:right
}

.vogue-grid .item {
  display:block
}

.vogue-grid .item > [class^="col-"] {
  -webkit-transition: margin 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: margin 300ms ease;
  transition: margin 300ms ease;
}

.vogue-grid .item > [class^="col-"] > .description {
  display: flex;
  margin: 12px 0 65px 0;
}

.vogue-grid .item:hover > [class^="col-"] {
  margin-left: 3vw
}

.vogue-grid .item > [class^="col-"] > .description > .insert {
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin-right: 16%
}
```

```html
            <main>
                <div class="vogue-grid">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <a class="item" href="#">
                            <div class="col-5-5 column">
                                <div class="pic"
                                    style="background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/384522/pexels-photo-384522.jpeg'); background-position: center center">
                                </div>
                                <div class="description">
                                    <div class="insert col-2">
                                        2018
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="caption col-6">
                                        <h2>Calendar</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                         <a class="item" href="#">
                            <div class="col-5-5 column right">
                                <div class="pic"
                                    style="background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/384522/pexels-photo-384522.jpeg'); background-position: center center">
                                </div>
                                <div class="description">
                                    <div class="insert col-2">
                                        2018
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="caption col-6">
                                        <h2>Arts</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because of the `float: right;` applied to the right item. It's already stuck to the right so the margin-left doesn't seem to affect the layout.